# How can I share files on the server with others users in internet?

Tags: centos, ssh, nginx, sftp, file-sharing

I have a linux server that I manage via SFTP and SSH. Some files are generated on the server through scripts. How can I make it so that I can give users on the Internet links to specific files (so that a specific user can only access one converse file) that are on this server? What technology stack do I need to learn? I would like to automate this process so that I run the script, it generates a file for the user and I would immediately see a link that I would give to the user. Is this even possible to do? If it is important, then the server has a domain name, and also runs on CentOS 7.

Comment: Via a web server (nginx/apache)? Via Torrent? Via FTP (vsftpd)?

Comment: I thought about nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already mention nginx: that's a HTTP server. So, that's an option, and probably a good one: make nginx share the directory with the file inside, and hand the URL to someone else. That's the "link" you're referring to (a link is, historically, something within a hypertext document, which typically points out a URL to go to, not the URL itself, but the last ~15 years these terms are used interchangeably).

So, you need to learn how to set up a directory that nginx shares (easy, documented all over the place), how to copy a file there (I'm sure you already know that!), make sure it has the right permissions (same), and how to send an email (which essentially takes setting up an email client in whatever scripting language you want to do this in).

Comment: you may need some NAT or forwarding rules from "public" internet to your local host. more preceisely you must tell your modem/router how to forward request to your internal network.

Comment: ah, he/she says the server has a domain name, so I'd guess it has a public IP address as well :)

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer, now I will digest it and understand it. Thank you!